# Indistinguishable Random Variables on a incomplete probability space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a not complete probability space for example the Borel-set:$$(R,\mathbb B, P)$$
If $X(\omega)$ is a random variable and $Y(\omega)=X(\omega)$ with probability one, is the $Y(\omega)$ a random variable? In the book I have read, Y is not a RV. But I dont know the reason for that. I mean somehow consider the set where Y is not equal to X, this set itsself must not be in Borel-Sigma-Algebra but it must contained in some set B from Borel-Sigma-Algebra with $P(B)=0$ and the preimage of such set B under Y must again be in the sigma algebra of $\Omega $

Edit:
Let's consider a subset $B \in \mathbb B(R)$ such that for an event $A\in \mathscr A$, $X(A)\in B$ and $Y(A)\in B'\cup A$ with $B'\subset B$, $A \notin \mathbb B(R)$ and there is a $N\in\mathbb B(R)$ such that $A \subset N, P(N)=0$. X is measurable since it is a r.v. However, as the space is incomplete, the set $B'\cup A$ is not in the $\mathbb B(R)$. So there is an event $A$ on the common domain of Y and X, whose image is in $\mathbb B(R)$ under X and is not in $\mathbb B(R)$ under $Y$. Does it somehow induce, that Y is not a R.V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more concretely, let your space be $[0,1]$ with the Borel sigma-algebra and the Lebesgue measure. Let $X$ be identically $1$, and let $Y$ be identically $1$ except that it is $0$ on some non-Borel subset of the standard Cantor set. (It is fairly elementary to construct one of these if you have a Lebesgue nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1]$ in hand.) Then $\{ 0 \}$ is Borel but $Y^{-1}(\{ 0 \})$ is not.

So yes, modification of a r.v. on a subset of a set with probability zero can create a function which is not an r.v.

Comment: Thanks. So Y will take value zero on some subset of Cantor set, which doesn't belong to Borel-Set. But how can I show that X=Y almost everywhere? The set $X \neq Y$ is a non-measurable set. Should Y take value zero on the whole Cantor set, then we will look for some interval, which include some subset of Cantorset and non-Borel and then use the argumentation as you mentioned at the end.

Comment: @quallenjäger $X=Y$ Lebesgue-almost everywhere, not $P$-almost everywhere. But the Lebesgue measure is the completion of $P$ in this case.

Comment: @quallenjäger In other words, $\{ X=Y \}$ contains a set of probability $1$, even though it is not measurable.

Comment: sorry for being annoying. I see your point, that you are keeping the Borel-Set instead of using Lebesgue Set and define a Lebesgue measure on it, which assign to each subset of Nullset the measure zero. But isn't a measure defined on a sigma-algebra. By assigning to each subset of Nullset zero measure, I will automatically assume that the sigma-algebra contains all subset of Nullset. Is it possible just complete the measure without complete the Sigma-algebra?

Comment: @quallenjäger No, the two go hand-in-hand.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand it. Since the Lebesgue measure is defined on a greater sigma algebra, there should be no problem to use it on a smaller sigma algebra. Therefore, even though $X \eq Y$ is not really measurable, it receives a measure.

Comment: @quallenjäger I mean it doesn't "really" receive a measure, but you may think of a set which contains a set of probability $1$ as being "large" even though we can't properly measure it.

Comment: Then we could also use the Borel-measure isn't it? This set would also receive measure 1. So there is a difference if I am looking at ${X=Y}$ being probability 1 or ${X \neq Y}$ being probability 0 on such not complete space? The former I can calculate it in dividing space into zero and non zero set. But the latter would be a problem if it is not Borel-measurable.

Comment: @quallenjäger The point is, the set $\{ X=Y \}$ in this example contains the complement of the Cantor set, plus some other stuff that is contained inside the Cantor set. So we have a peculiar situation: we will land in that set with probability $1$ (because we will land in a subset of it with probability $1$) but the probability measure doesn't assign it a measure anyway.

Comment: I have sent you message in chat. I dont know how to link it. Let's discuss in chat